# PFIncrementalStore for iOS...Has anyone made it work?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, nsincrementalstore

Has anyone had any success with PFIncremental store? Here: http://sbonami.github.io/PFIncrementalStore/

When I load of the sample project, then add my Parse keys and start the app, I don't see any objects appear in Parse. Additionally, if I implement my own test of the library, and try to save an object, it does not appear in the Parse interface.

Any assistance or insight would be appreciated. Please let me know if there is more information that I can provide.

Thanks in advance.